# Pandas: Nested iteration of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataframe which contains two columns: 'rep_id' and 'values'. The second column is a list of numbers.

I would like to compute all possible pairs of 'rep_id' and then find the values that are common to the pairs.

The final Dataframe would look like: 'rep_id1', 'rep_id2', 'values' where 'values' represents a list of common elements between the lists of 'rep_id1' and 'rep_id2'.

One way to do this is to create a nested loop and go through pairs of rep_ids but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: *"I would like to compute all possible pairs of 'rep_id' and then find the values that are common to the rep_ids."*.... between all possible pairs you mean?

Comment: Yes between the pairs

Comment: Do you have sample data and attempted code?

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(['A','B','C','D','E','A','B','C','A'],[1,2,3,4,5,2,3,5,5]),columns=['rep_id','val'])

df = df.sort('val')

cartesian_product = pd.merge(df, df,on='val')
cartesian_product = cartesian_product[cartesian_product['rep_id_x'] != cartesian_product['rep_id_y']]
cartesian_product[['val','rep_id_x','rep_id_y']]
```

df:

```
  rep_id  val
0      A    1
1      B    2
5      A    2
2      C    3
6      B    3
3      D    4
4      E    5
7      C    5
8      A    5
```

cartesian_product:

```
    val rep_id_x rep_id_y
2     2        B        A
3     2        A        B
6     3        C        B
7     3        B        C
11    5        E        C
12    5        E        A
13    5        C        E
15    5        C        A
16    5        A        E
17    5        A        C
```